# Detecting a modified vs new record, and updating a modified record with ASP.NET MVC 2, EF v4, POCOs, and Repository pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, repository-pattern

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2, Entity Framework v4, the ADO.NET C# POCO Entity Generator, and the Repository pattern.  Lots of buzzwords!

### The Setup:

I have a repository, *IPartiesRepository*.  I have a *Party* object and a *Party_Identification* object.  Party being a generic term for a person or organization.

On the SQL/physical model level, the Party table has a single primary key, PartyId.  The Party_Identifications table has a composite key made up of three fields -- PartyId, IdentificationTypeCode, and IdentificationStartDate.

I have a strongly typed (to *Party*) view which lists Party information and associated identifications.  A user can edit a party's identification; the edit links are generated via an ActionLink that looks like so:

```
<h3>Identification Data</h3>
<% foreach (var Identification in Model.Party_Identifications) { %>
   <%: Identification.IdentificationTypeCode %>: <%: Identification.IdentificationValue %> - <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditIdentification", new { partyId = Identification.PartyId, idTypeCode = Identification.IdentificationTypeCode, startDate = Identification.PartyIdentificationStartDate })%><br />
<% } %>
```

The *EditIdentification()* method in the *PartyController* looks like:

```
public ActionResult EditIdentification(int partyId, string idTypeCode, string startDate)
{
    var party = partiesRepository.GetPartyById(partyId);
    var identification = party.Party_Identifications.Where(x => x.PartyId == partyId && x.IdentificationTypeCode == idTypeCode && x.PartyIdentificationStartDate == DateTime.Parse(startDate)).First();
    return View("EditIdentification", identification);
}
```

The *EditIdentification* view allows the user to modify the identification record via a basic form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("EditIdentification", "Party")) { %>
<%: Html.EditorForModel()%>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
<% } %>
```

### The Problem:

I have another *EditIdentification()* method in the PartyController that handles the save.  I am attempting to see if there we are updating an existing identification record, or creating a new one (I also have a *Create()* method in the *PartyController* that returns the *EditIdentification* view with a Party_Identification object as the model).

I know there's a better way to do what I'm doing below (specifically, detecting a modified vs new record, and updating a modified record) -- how can I improve this?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditIdentification(Party_Identification partyidentification)
{
    TryUpdateModel(partyidentification);
    if (partyidentification.CreationDate == DateTime.Parse("01/01/0001"))
    {
        partyidentification.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
        partyidentification.CreatedByName = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        partyidentification.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
        partyidentification.ModifiedByName = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
    }

    // TODO: Validation goes here...

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var party = partiesRepository.GetPartyById(partyidentification.PartyId) as Party;
        int partyCount = party.Party_Identifications
            .Where(x => x.PartyId == partyidentification.PartyId &&
                   x.IdentificationTypeCode == partyidentification.IdentificationTypeCode &&
                   x.PartyIdentificationStartDate == partyidentification.PartyIdentificationStartDate)
            .Count();
        if (partyCount == 0)
        {
            party.Party_Identifications.Add(partyidentification);
        }
        else
        {
            var idtoupdate = party.Party_Identifications
            .Where(x => x.PartyId == partyidentification.PartyId && 
                        x.IdentificationTypeCode == partyidentification.IdentificationTypeCode && 
                        x.PartyIdentificationStartDate == partyidentification.PartyIdentificationStartDate)
            .First();
            idtoupdate.IdentificationValue = partyidentification.IdentificationValue;
            idtoupdate.PartyIdentificationEndDate = partyidentification.PartyIdentificationEndDate;
            idtoupdate.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
            idtoupdate.ModifiedByName = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
        }
        partiesRepository.SaveParty(party);

        return View("Edit", party);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Edit", partyidentification);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be repeating your code which it not needed:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var party = partiesRepository.GetPartyById(partyidentification.PartyId) as Party;

                int partyCount = party.Party_Identifications
                    .Where(x => x.PartyId == partyidentification.PartyId &&
                           x.IdentificationTypeCode == partyidentification.IdentificationTypeCode &&
                           x.PartyIdentificationStartDate == partyidentification.PartyIdentificationStartDate)
                           .first();

                if (partyCount == null)
                {
                    party.Party_Identifications.Add(partyidentification);
                }
                else
                {
                    partyCount.IdentificationValue = partyidentification.IdentificationValue;
                    partyCount.PartyIdentificationEndDate = partyidentification.PartyIdentificationEndDate;
                    partyCount.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
                    partyCount.ModifiedByName = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
                }
                partiesRepository.SaveParty(party);

                return View("Edit", party);
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Edit", partyidentification);
            }
```